# How to find the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[n\sin\left(1 \over n\right)\right]^{n^{3}} $

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty {\left(n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^{n^3} } \,\,\sim \,\,\,\sum_{n = 1}^\infty { \left(n\left(\,\,\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{6n^3}+o\left (\frac{1}{n}\right)\,\, \right)\right)^{n^3} } $$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} { \left(1-\frac{1}{6n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^{n^3} } \sim \lim_{n \to \infty} q^n =0\,\,\,\,(0<q<1)$$
Does this series converge?

Comment: Should you possible delete garbage from the edited post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the new version: Starting from some $n$, the $n$th term of the series will be less than or equal to $e^{-\tfrac1{20}n}$, and so the series converges.

Comment: To get more comprehension: I can say, the majorant for this series $\sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{1}{e^{n/20}}}$. Your expression too much abstract for me. I need to drive it at familiar criterion.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\lim(1-\frac am+o(\frac1m))^m=e^{-a}$. Derive from this that if $a>0$, then $\lim(1-\frac a{n^2}+o(\frac1{n^2}))^{n^3}=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, overwork myself. I wrote a limit, but I mean the sum of series. I correct this question... Look at it, please.

Answer (score 3):

Assume the limit exists and has the value $L$.  Then

$$\begin{align} \log{L} &=\lim_{n\to\infty} n^3 \log{\left ( n \sin{\frac1{n}}\right )} \\&= \lim_{n\to\infty} n^3 \log{\left (1-\frac1{6 n^2} \right )} \\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty} -\frac{n}{6} \\ &= -\infty\end{align}$$

Thus, $L=0$.

Comment: this way, you do not prove that the limit exists (and you can't look for $\log L$ when $L\le 0$ anyway).

Comment: @mookid The terms of the sequence are positive $\implies$ their logarithms exist. Then we compute their limit, it is $-\infty$ $\implies$ the sequence itself converges to $0$.

Comment: @Vladimir I insist: you can't write such thing as $\log L$! you can always compute $\log u_n$ but that's all. And my first sentence remains.

Comment: @Alex Are you sure? ;)

Comment: @mookid no we can't write $\log L$. But once we prove that $u_n>0$ and $\log u_n$ tends to $-\infty$, we see that $u_n\to0$. So Ron Gordon's proof is technically incorrect but easily amended, that is what I tried to say.

Comment: @Vladimir et al: all you need do is assume that $n \gt 2/\pi$ and you have the positivity, as $\sin$ is decreasing within the first quadrant as $n$ increases without bound.  I am not sure where this answer is incorrect, as it is not a proof of existence. (The OP did not request one.)

Comment: Ron Gordon: The only thing which is technically incorrect in your answer is to write $\log 0=-\infty$ (although, as far as I am concerned, this is harmless jargon which I often use myself).  My answer has been intended to show that @mookid's criticism is irrelevant except for one tiny point, not to attack your computations. By the way, $n>2/\pi$ for all positive integer $n$ ;).

Comment: @Vladimir the crucial point here is that Ron Gordon's ansswer does not address the issue of existence.

Comment: @mookid nor is the issue addressed in OP's question. Anyway, this nitpicking makes little sense, do you agree? And I definitely do not wish to serve as a referee for two people whose reputation is by orders of magnitude larger than mine;)

Comment: this kind of *nitpicking* makes the difference between true and wrong in a Math exam.

Comment: @mookid: You are confusing the requirement of being logically complete with merely answering the OP's question.  The OP did not state anywhere that he wanted a proof of existence.  Nor does every limit calculation require one.

Comment: I train on my own to master enter exams. And there will be a first question - find a limit. I'm wonder, to get a right answer not enough to find right limit value. Your dispute means, that first I must do for pure formality is checking the limit for existence, even if it is evident?